# Windows Phone 8 PhoneGap Barcodescanner

Tags: windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I've been trying to use Windows Phone 8 with PhoneGap and the Plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/WindowsPhone/BarcodeScanner) for BarcodeScanning. But I don't know how to start.

I integrated a `<a href="#" class="btn" onclick="window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan">Scan Code</a>` in my index.html, but VS2012 is only telling me `Error:"Unable to get property 'barcodeScanner' of undefined or null reference file:x-wmapp0:www/index.html Line:31"`

Could anyone give me a Hand?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not included either cordova.windows-x.x.x.js or barcodescanner.js.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in barcodeScanner.js.

In the bottom of the file it says

```
Cordova.addConstructor(function() {
```

Change Cordova to cordova (lowercase) and you're good to go.

Next, if you get the error

```
Error::Plugin not allowed in config.xml. org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner
```

while trying to scan, add the following to your config.xml in project root:

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but this is the step i did to make it work:

Add the BarcodeScanner and ZXingVer1_7 dll in your project.

Add the BarcodeScanner.cs into your project.(must be at the root of the project)

Add `<plugin name="BarcodeScanner" />` to your config.xml.

Add the barcodescanner.js to your "www" directory.

Add `<script type="text/javascript" src="../barcodescanner.js"></script>`
 to your html page after your cordova.js declaration. (the path may be different depending where you put your html)

In your barcodescanner.js , make sure that all the "cordova" reference is not write like this: "Cordova"

In your barcodescanner.js , in the line who's begin with:"return cordova.exec(...", replace the string "barcodeScanner" by "(Your project name).barcodeScanner"

To use it, just add this to where you need a barcode scan :

```
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function (result) {
        alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                  "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                  "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                  "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
          }, function (error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        });
```